# Does reloading a checkpoint reset P.E.C. challenge progress?

Tags: splinter-cell-conviction

If you complete a PEC challenge in one game, then restart from last checkpoint, is that PEC challenge completion reset?  Or is it possible to continue replaying the same section to complete other PEC challenges?

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 kinds of challenges to complete:

- Prepare and Execute
- Vanish
- Splinter Cell

For Prepare and Execute and Vanish there are 3 levels to each challenge (achieved by completing the task a certain number of times), these do not get reset with each game.

The Splinter Cell challenges are one and done. As soon as you complete the challenge once you gain points, and the challenge is marked as complete.

Here is a complete listing of the challenges:

### *Prepare and Execute Challenges*

- Neutralize an enemy using Death From Above
- Neutralize an enemy using Grab From Ledge
- Neutralize 5 enemies in a row without being detected
- Neutralize an enemy with a headshot without alerting other enemies
- Neutralize at least 2 enemies in a single Mark & Execute
- Neutralize 3 enemies at the same time with a single frag grenade
- Neutralize at least 3 enemies by detonating a remote explosion gadget
- Neutralize an enemy who is stunned by a flashbang or EMP gadget
- Use the mirror or snake camera to mark an enemy, then neutralize him
- Use the sonar goggles to mark an enemy, then neutralize him
- Perform hand to hand takedowns in the shadows without alerting other enemies
- Make noise with the sticky camera to attract an enemy, and neutralize him

### Vanish Challenges

- Once you are spotted, vanish without neutralizing any enemies
- Peform a hand to hand takedown against an enemy who is investigating your last known position
- Neutralize an enemy while standing at least 10 meters from your last known position
- Use the portable EMP to vanish. Stun at least 3 enemies while escaping from a combat situation
- Use the flashbang to vanish. Escape from a combat situation
- Stun at least 3 enemies with a single EMP grenade
- Free your team-mate from a choke hold in any Multiplayer game mode
- Revive your team-mate in any Multiplayer game mode

### Splinter Cell Challenges

- Neutralize 4 enemies with a single Mark & Execute
- Complete a level without being spotted and without retrying
- Complete a level without firing a single shot and without retrying
- Neutralize 10 enemies in a row without being detected
- Neutralize 15 enemies with a single magazine using an assault rifle without reloading
- Neutralize 10 enemies with a single magazine using a pistol without reloading.
- Take an enemy into human shield and bash him against a wooden door to shatter it.
- Knock an enemy down by throwing another enemy onto him
- Throw an enemy so he falls 10 or more meters
- Neutralize 3 enemies using a single trap or explosive
- Attract an enemy by disabling a security device, then neutralize him
- Neutralize an enemy while he is investigating a car alarm
- Mark and Execute 3 enemies while holding a human shield
- Nuetralize 3 enemies who are stunned by a single gadget
- Crush an enemy on the other side of a door by bashing into it or kicking it down
- Shatter a window by throwing an enemy through it
- Use 3 different special moves during a single interrogation
- In any CO-OP game mode, when you are knocked down, sit up and neutralize 5 enemies before your team-mate revives you
- Remain undetected for 10 minutes after vanishing

Answer (score 0):

PEC challenge progress and completion are not lost when you reload a checkpoint or exit the game (via the menu), so yes, you can farm repetition challenges and complete multiple challenges by reloading a favorable checkpoint over and over.